# How to use common methods in some other class and use that in another class android?

Tags: android, android-activity, soap, android-ksoap2

I am using soap in which the code is running fine but there are some common methods which I need to use in some other class and use it in all activities.
But I don't know how to separate the methods and use it. Please guide me to solve this. Here is my code..

```
class A extend Activity{
private String sessionId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.sortfilterclick);
  new CommonElement().execute();
  }
  class CommonElement extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
 ProgressDialog dialog;

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
  super.onPreExecute();
  dialog = new ProgressDialog(CommonElement.this);
 dialog.show();
  dialog.setCancelable(false);
   }

  @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
 try {
// these are all common
 SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
 env.dotNet = false;
 env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
 env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.API_URL);
sessionId = Utils.readPreferences(CommonElement.this,Constants.SESSION_ID, null);
if (sessionId == null) {
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "login");
    request.addProperty("username", "Clothing");
    request.addProperty("apiKey", "Clothing");
    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
      Object result = env.getResponse();
     sessionId = result.toString();
    Utils.savePreferences(CommonElement.this,
       Constants.SESSION_ID, sessionId);
     }// till this it's common
    //here json reuest datas varies in json.put()...
    SoapObject requests = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "call");//these are common
    requests.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);//these are common
    requests.addProperty("resourcePath","sortap.Action"); //this will change for every property
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();// these will change 
      json.put("page", "1");
      json.put("limit", "10");
       json.put("name", sortName);
      json.put("order", sortOrder);
      json.put("id", "3");
      json.put("cate_id", "4");
      String params = json.toString();
      requests.addProperty("args", params);
     env.setOutputSoapObject(requests);
     androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
     Object results = env.getResponse();
    //based on various request and response this varies.
     if (results.toString() != null) {
      JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(results.toString());
      JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("results");
      for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
     String id = object.getString("id");
       String productName = object.getString("product_name");
       String imageUrl = object.getString("image_url");
      int productPrice = object.getInt("price");
     }
       }
       } 
     catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
      }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.cancel();
        }
```

==========================
           this is my changes that  I done..==============================

```
    public final class SoapCommon {

public static String sessionId;

public static String id;

public static String  SessionIdNull(){
    try{
    SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
    env.dotNet = false;
    env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
    env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
            Constants.API_URL);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(
            Constants.NAMESPACE, "login");
    request.addProperty("username", "Clothing");
    request.addProperty("apiKey", "Clothing");
    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
    Object result = env.getResponse();
    sessionId = result.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return sessionId;
}

    public static final void noSession(){
    try{
        SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
        env.dotNet = false;
        env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
        env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                Constants.API_URL);
        SoapObject requests = new SoapObject(
                Constants.NAMESPACE, "call");
        requests.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
        env.setOutputSoapObject(requests);
        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
        Object results = env.getResponse();
        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
        Object result = env.getResponse();
        sessionId = result.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

and in another activity:

```
        void doInBackground {

              try {
                        // here 
                        sessionId = Utils.readPreferences(
                                SortFilterPopupActivity.this,
                                Constants.SESSION_ID, null);
                        if (sessionId == null) {
                            // I splitted and used but don't know how to use here.
                            Utils.savePreferences(
                                    CommonElement.this,
                                    Constants.SESSION_ID, sessionId);
                        }

                        // same here too
                        env.setOutputSoapObject(requests);
                        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
                        Object results = env.getResponse();
                        Log.e("Sort results", results.toString());
                        if (results.toString() != null) {
                            ........

                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    return null;
                }

}
```

But strucked in this issue.

Comment: Simply make a class and put all the methods that you want ,overload and override constructor of that class and in that constructor call the desired function and also pass values through constructor.

Comment: please check my update and guide me

Answer (score 1):

If the methods can be instanceless then create a utilytie class like so:

```
public Utils {
 public static void doSomethingUsefull(Param p) {

 }
}
```

Then you can use this method/s of this class without an instance in any other class like so:

```
...
Utils.doSomethingUfesul(p);
...
```

Other wise create a real class with an constructor and so on.

```
public StatefullUtils {
 public StatefullUtils(Param p) {
  this.p = p;
  ...
 }

 public void doSomethingUsefull() {
  p++;
  ...
 }
}
```

Then you can use this class everywhere else by:

```
StatefullUtils utils = new StatefullUtils(p);
utils.doSomethingUsefull();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class and define a method within it..

**Step 1 :** Create Class & Define Methods..

**Example :**

```
public class CommonUtils {

    // always create public method and define it a static method
    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

}
```

Here, You can define public variables too, that can used all over the application..

**Step 2 :** Use it in another class..

> Syntax : **YOURCLASS.YOURMETHOD(PARAMETERS);**

**Example :**

```
if (CommonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {

    //do your code... 
    //i have defined it in IF condition because my method returns a value.. you can define it `void`...
}
```